# Вычисления n-го корня

Tags: xcode, swift

Здравствуйте. Разбираясь в языке возник вопрос вычисления корня числа. Мне лень писать свою функцию и думал есть стандартные. такие как вычисления степени это

```
Pow(Double, Double)
```

А вычисления квадратного корня

```
sqrt(Double)
```

Пробовал забивать в `pow` дробную степень соответствующую нужному корню 1/x. Но вычисление идет не точно, притом неточность увеличивается от степени корня. 
Пример:

```
pow(1000.0, 1.0/3.0)
```

Должно получится `10`, а получаю `9.999999999999998`

Может и есть стандартные, но я не могу найти. Можете подсказать если имеется данная встроенная функция.

Функции тестирую на онлайн площадке Swiftа.

Comment: Как Вы выводите результат?

Comment: это вещественная арифметика и результат достаточно точный - 6*10e-14 %. очень хорошая точность!

Comment: @KoVadim, результат-то хороший, но сколько ни сталкивался с подобными задачами - если должно быть в результате 10.0 (или другой целый результат), всегда 10.0 и получал.

Comment: многие функции печати иногда обманывают и выдают результат в более ожидаемой форме.

Что бы понять, что результат, который Вы получили, абсолютно правильный, получите кубический корень с 10.

Comment: @KoVadim, собственно, поэтому и спрашивал как автор вопроса выводит результат. P.S. из 10 получил 2.15443469003188.

Comment: @VAndrJ  Я просто тестирую функции на онлайн площадке Swiftа.

Comment: @KoVadim Я понимаю что точность очень хорошая, даже очень. И это превосходно. И кубический корень из 10 я сравнивал. все хорошо. Но если должно быть целое число, 10^3 = 1000 ,а 1000^(1/3) = 10, ну не как не 9.99999999998.

Comment: а вводили то вы не 1000, а 1000.0. Нужно - напишите свою функцию для целых чисел.

Comment: @JoMax, значит это бок самой площадки. Как при логировании, так и при выводе на устройстве 1000^(1/3) всегда дает 10.0

Comment: @VAndrJ  Да вы правы какой-то баг. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Наилучший вариант - установить Xcode и тестировать в родном окружении. Если нет Mac для этих целей, можно установить виртуалку и в ней работать/учиться. Тем более, нынче такие виртуалки, что получают обновления наравне с реальными компьютерами от Apple. А производительности даже ноутбука 6-летней давности с головой хватает для сносной работы.

Для совсем ознакомительных целей да, подойдет и онлайн-площадка, но если вылезет какая-то проблема, в первую очередь нужно проверить, а не проблема ли это самой площадки? (хотя к Xcode тоже есть претензии)

Comment: У меня Mac. Спасибо, за подробное расписание ваших слов которые вы приводили в комментариях ранее.